# How to check if a string exists in a object which is stored in a hashmap?

Tags: java, collections, hashmap

I have created a Employee class with 3 parameters.

1. Id
2. Name
3. Age

**Requirement:** Search based on Name. This is a case where all employees have a unique name. Its mandatory to add the objects with key as id. There are rare cases where it is required to search based on name.

**What i have done :**

Within the class I am overriding hashCode and Equals method.

I am adding a list of these objects into the hashmap with id as key and value as Employee object

But while adding or searching from a hashmap both the methods do not get called

So what is the use of these methods in terms on hasmap?

Employee Class

```
public class Employee {

    private int id;
    private String name;
    private int age;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        return name.hashCode();
    }

    public boolean equals(Employee emp) {
        if (emp == null)
            return false;
        else if (emp.name.equalsIgnoreCase(this.name))
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
}
```

Main Method:

```
public class HashMapTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Employee emp1=new Employee();
        emp1.setId(1);
        emp1.setName("Maclean");
        emp1.setAge(24);

        Employee emp2=new Employee();
        emp2.setId(2);
        emp2.setName("Sampath");
        emp2.setAge(25);

        Employee emp3=new Employee();
        emp3.setId(3);
        emp3.setName("Achar");
        emp3.setAge(27);

        Employee emp4=new Employee();
        emp4.setId(4);
        emp4.setName("Sudheer");
        emp4.setAge(25);

        Employee emp5=new Employee();
        emp5.setId(5);
        emp5.setName("Kunder");
        emp5.setAge(25);

        HashMap<Integer, Employee> empmap=new HashMap();
        empmap.put(emp1.getId(), emp1);
        empmap.put(emp2.getId(), emp2);
        empmap.put(emp3.getId(), emp3);
        empmap.put(emp4.getId(), emp4);
        empmap.put(emp5.getId(), emp5);

        Employee emp=new Employee();
        emp.setName("Maclean");
        System.out.println(empmap.containsValue(emp));

        System.exit(1);
    }

}
```

Update Solution:

Thanks for all the answers.

**1. hashCode method gets called only if the Key is a object and the method exists within the Key Class**

**2. Equals(Employee emp) is causing function overloading instead of overriding. I should have used equals(Object o)**

Changes in the code to resolve the issue

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (o == null)
        return false;
    if (!(o instanceof Employee))
        return false;

    Employee emp = (Employee) o;
    if (emp.name.equalsIgnoreCase(this.name))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Comment: If `id` is the unique attribute, shouldn't `hashCode` be based on that instead of name? Also, the `hashCode` method is called on the object that is the key to the map, i.e. the id, not the value, i.e. the Employee.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not overriding Object.equals(Object o), which you need to do. You are overloading it. That's why it's not being called.

Try this equals() instead:

```
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (o == null)
        return false;
    if (!(o instanceof Employee))
        return false;

    Employee emp = (Employee) o;
    if (emp.name.equalsIgnoreCase(this.name))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Comment: If you're doing equality checks with equalsIgnoreCase, your hashCode implementation must also be case insensitive.

Answer (score 2):

> Within the class I am overriding hashCode and Equals method.
>   [...]
>   But while adding or searching from a hashmap both the methods do not get called
>   So what is the use of these methods in terms on hasmap?

If you have a `Map<Key, Value>`, and you call `put` or `get` on that map, then `hashCode` and `equals` are called on the `Key` class, not on the `Value` class.

In your case, that means that if you do `empmap.put(emp1.getId(), emp1);` then it checks the hash of `emp1.getId()` and whether that's already in the map. So it's normal that those methods are not called on your `Employee` class.

Also, if `id` is the "unique" attribute, then `Employee.hashCode` should probably be based on that (and `equals`, too, to be consistent with `hashCode`), and as noted in another answer, `Employee.equals` should accept any `Object` as parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I did not test, but try it with

```
HashMap<Integer, Employee> empmap=new HashMap<>();
```

or even

```
HashMap<Integer, Employee> empmap=new HashMap<Integer, Employee>();
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done very nicely in Java 8 using streams.

```
empmap.values().stream().anyMatch(emp.getName().equals(searchedName));
```

This takes the set of all entries in the map and see if the stream matches any entry that has a name equal to your `searchedName`.

In a comparable you can also fetch all matching names by using [`Stream.filter()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#filter-java.util.function.Predicate-)

Implementing a different version of equals/hashcode is tricky because it changes the behavior of the class in many ways.

Comment: ... which is larger and more complicated than `containsValue(o)`. BTW: i would use `emp.values().stream()....`

Comment: Good point on the values, I will update the answer accordingly. The proble with containsValue is that it only allows to use equals, which has a lot of other implications if you change the meaning.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution for your problem is to add this method to the Employee class.
Silently, HashMap uses the equals(Object o) of a value object (in this case Employee) for checking the existence of that object.

```
@Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        Employee employee = (Employee) o;

        if (name != null ? !name.equals(employee.name) : employee.name != null) return false;

        return true;
    }
```

Be careful, This implementation of equals(Object o) just works on the name and it does not check other fields.

```
Employee emp=new Employee();
emp.setId(10);
emp.setName("Maclean");
emp.setAge(240);

System.out.println(empmap.containsValue(emp));
System.out.println(emp1.equals(emp));
```

is

true
true